# Создание клиент-серверного приложения C#

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер

Раньше я всегда создавал приложения на C# с помощью `WinForms` или `WPF`, в которых напрямую обращался к локальной базе данных через запросы с помощью `SqlCommand` или `EntityFramework`. Но как я понимаю это не лучшее решение, если, например, создавать приложение не только для себя, а для нескольких пользователей.

Если я правильно понимаю, то клиент-серверное приложение - это клиент, с которым работает пользователь и который отправляет запросы к серверу, и собственно сам сервер, который принимает и обрабатывает запросы, а после отдаёт какой-то ответ.

Клиент - это допустим `WPF`-приложение, в котором мы должны отправлять запросы к серверу, но я не совсем понимаю, что именно должно выполнять роль сервера, на чем его писать и как подключать к клиенту.

Так как я никогда не работал с API и не создавал серверной части, то мне непонятно что именно гуглить для ответа на свой вопрос, всё, что я нашёл - это что сервер можно создать на [ASP.NET WebAPI](https://skillbox.ru/media/code/pishem_messendzher_na_c_chast_1_vyerstka/), но в данной статье только первая часть, посвященная созданию клиента.

Итак, если обобщить всё выше написанное, то мой вопрос - как и на чем можно написать сервер для клиент-серверного приложения, где клиент - это `WPF`-приложение, и как потом этот сервер подключить к клиенту.

P.S Понимаю, что вопрос достаточно тривиальный для C#-программистов, но так как сталкиваюсь впервые с этим, то мне подойдут ссылки на статьи, названия библиотек, ссылки на документацию и так далее, любая информация чтобы понять куда рыть для ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: ASP.NET Core WebAPI - нормальное решение

Comment: плюсую комментарий @aepot, вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) вы можете почитать подробнее о том как сделать такое приложение

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть в этом направлении, @iKuzmychov может быть есть какая-то статья
по созданию клиент-серверного приложения именно wpf + asp,net?

Comment: Клиентское и серверное приложение создаются отдельно. Как отправлять GET и POST запросы на сервер, я думаю, разберетесь.

Comment: @Pekor в WPF клиенте нет особо отличающегося, от того же WinForms. План довольно простой: `1.` создаёте модели (классы) для таблиц базы данных и выносите их в отдельный проект "XXX.Models", чтобы ссылаться на него из других проектов `2.` делаете проект "XXX.WebApi" - серверную часть приложения на ASP.NET, в которой создаёте контроллеры, которые взаимодействуют с БД и возвращают JSON в ответ `3.` Создаёте проект "XXX.WebApiClient", в котором создаёте классы (обычно хватает одного), которые делают HTTP запросы к вашему API и парсят ответы в C# объекты `4.` Используете API-клиет в WPF приложении

Comment: @aepot я так понимаю в `solution` будет 2 проекта - проект wpf и  проект asp,net?

Comment: Да хоть разные солюшны, без разницы, технически эти проекты ничего не связывает.